# Importing specific data in Python from multiple files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python and need a bit of help in importing data from multiple files? There are 24 files for each day (hourly) and each file (a dictionary) has 26 elements. I need to import two sets of data (time vs frequency) in Python. Will really appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: You need to show us the code that you have tried, one of the multiple files that you're talking about, etc.

Comment: You want to read multiple file at a time ! so read one file first then try on multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how SO usually works....

You do some work .... it does wrong ... share it ... we will assist

However this is how I would have a look at this

```
from glob import glob

for file in glob("myfiles"):
    with open(file,"rt") as  datafile:
        data=datafile.read()
```

If the file is a dictionary ? You mean JSON or pickle  ??

But is a string then - BUT eval is VERY DANGEROUS to use.

```
str1="{'bill': 2, 'tim': 1}"
eval(str1)
```

Over to you